# What Documents to use for Financial Documentation for Canada

Tags: canada, money, proof-provenance-of-funds

I have this Documents For Canada Visa Application and Please I do need genuine and up to date responses.

Asides the normal documents for the visa Application which I would be uploading all online, Now i have this additional Documents which I want to use for Financial Documents

I have a letter from my employer detailing that they would sponsor my trip for a Biomedical Conference. The company is responsible for Perdiem, Hotels etc which I would be using in Canada, as they wouldnt be giving me company bank statements. I have my own bank statements as well but I am getting the documents for the 2 to submit for the visa application as i would be submitting soon. (For a Conference for September)

Please advise if I am on the Right track. Need replies from people with very similar experiences.